# With gcsfuse, how much remaining space is available in a bucket when mounted?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcsfuse

I'm about to evaluate gcsfuse for use in a system with a database daemon. The daemon is peculiar. It computes its usable available disk space **subtactively**, rather than additively; that is, it ensures that it uses all of the available space, **except** for a reserved portion of disk.

[GSE documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/) suggests that storage is indefinitely large, which I assume means that the "disk" size of the bucket will appear as some ridiculous or unexpected number. What actually happens? Is there a way to instruct the `gcsfuse` binary to set a maximum bucket size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the database uses `statfs` to find free space, gcsfuse [simulates](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcsfuse/blob/284558bd039f4859a5fd4b465639fe69725e34a0/internal/fs/fs.go#L947-L953) 1 PiB of free space. (This is not guaranteed in the documentation anywhere and is subject to change.)

There are tests that confirms this works on [macOS](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcsfuse/blob/284558bd039f4859a5fd4b465639fe69725e34a0/tools/integration_tests/gcsfuse_darwin_test.go#L66-L71) and [linux](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcsfuse/blob/284558bd039f4859a5fd4b465639fe69725e34a0/tools/integration_tests/gcsfuse_linux_test.go#L48-L54).

Comment: Reproduced this on NixOS, my target platform. Thanks for the detailed answer.